# Creating functions to retrieve values of properties retrieved via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Im writing code to transfer data of my ORM entities into a dataset. Because i dont want to write special code for each type defining which properties need to be written down, i am currently using reflection (calling GetProperties on the type of the entities, building up a DataTable for this type and then calling GetValue on each Propertyinfo for each entity). Status quo: It works, but it is slow.

Now i´m trying to build up a method that is returning a function to retrieve the value of certain properties fast, but i am having a hard time here. This is what i got so far:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// creates a func that will return the value of the given property 
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="T">type of the entity</typeparam>
  /// <param name="propertyInfo">the property to get the value from</param>
  /// <returns>a function accepting an instance of T and returning the value of the property</returns>
  private Func<T, object> CreateGetPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   {         
     MethodInfo getMethod = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
     return (Func<T, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, object>), getMethod);          
  }
```

These are my unit tests:

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestGenerateDelegate()
  {
     var employee = new Employee
     {            
        Id = 1,
        Name = "TestEmployee",            
     };

     Func<Employee, object> getIdValueFunc = CreateGetPropertyFunc<Employee>(typeof(Employee).GetProperty("Id"));
     Assert.AreEqual(1, getIdValueFunc(employee));
  }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGenerateDelegateName()
    {
        var employee = new Employee
        {
            Name = "Test"
        };

        Func<Employee, object> getNameValueFunc = CreateGetPropertyFunc<Employee>(typeof(Employee).GetProperty("Name"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Test", getNameValueFunc(employee));
    }
```

When i call the first one, an ArgumentException with the message "Exception while binding to the target method" (translated, may be different text) is thrown . The second test passes instead.

I´m pretty sure i´m not correctly handling that CreateDelegate method. Could anyone point me to the right direction, please?

Update:

As PetSerAI statet, it seems to be a problem with the variance, values primitive types cannot be returned as object via CreateDelegate...

Comment: Delegate return type variance does not work with value types. You can not bind method returning `int` to delegate returning `object`.

Comment: You are right, its working with the Name property, but not with Id. What a pitty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression trees to dynamically create delegate, which reference specified property:

```
private Func<T, object> CreateGetPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
    ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(
        Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(p, propertyInfo), typeof(object)),
        p
    ).Compile();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just invoke your `getMethod`:

```
private Func<T, object> CreateGetPropertyFunc<T>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
{
    MethodInfo getMethod = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
    return o => getMethod.Invoke(o, BindingFlags.Default, null, null, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Comment: That may be something that we Germans call "dangerous half-knowledge", but isn´t invoking via methodinfo slow compared to a direct call? That´s what i want to avoid...

Answer (score 1):

`CreateDelegate(Type, MethodInfo)` binds to a static method (you have no static method, which is why you are getting the error)

You can only use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` for instance methods with this version: `CreateDelegate(Type, Object, MethodInfo)`

> Creates a delegate of the specified type that represents the specified
>   static or instance method, with the specified first argument.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate(v=vs.110).aspx

As per PetSerAl's comment, you should pass 'null' as the 'first argument' to create an "open delegate" into which you would pass the instance.

```
    // In this case, the delegate has one more 
    // argument than the instance method; this argument comes
    // at the beginning, and represents the hidden instance
    // argument of the instance method. Use delegate type D1
    // with instance method M1.
    //
    d1 = (D1) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(D1), null, mi1);

    // An instance of C must be passed in each time the 
    // delegate is invoked.
    //
    d1(c1, "Hello, World!");
```

Comment: `CreateDelegate(Type, MethodInfo)` can create delegate from non static method: `Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, string>), typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"))`. [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/53cz7sc6.aspx#Anchor_2) says: *In the .NET Framework version 2.0, this method overload also can create open instance method delegates; that is, delegates that explicitly supply the hidden first argument of instance methods.*

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that -- so he needs to then use the other overload.  I will edit my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go generic all the way and let the compiler create the delegate for you?

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static Func<T, TProp> CreateGetPropertyFunc<T, TProp>(this T obj, Func<T, TProp> func)
    {
        return func;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var getterForId = employee.CreateGetPropertyFunc(x => x.Id);
int result = getterForId(employee);
// result can now be 'int' and doesn't have to be 'object'
```

---

If you don't have an actual instance of `T` upfront, or just don't want an extension-method approach:

```
public Func<T, object> CreateGetPropertyFunc<T>(Func<T, object> func)
{
    return func;
}
```

Then:

```
var getterForId = CreateGetPropertyFunc<Employee>(x => x.Id);
object result = getterForId(employee);
// result must be 'object' (unless explicitly casted)
```

---

(The former is better in terms of performance because value-types like `int` will not get boxed, and type safety is preserved)

Comment: May be i misunderstand you. I dont want to write all those lines for all those entity properties i have; i want to dynamically get all the properties of a type via reflection and create fast access methods to extract the property values. Whats the point of writing a lambda "x=> x.Id" to get... the id?

Comment: @Udontknow, The "point of writing a Lambda" is that the compiler translates it to your desired `Func<>` and you don't have to use Reflection. Also **1)** it's better in terms of performance and **2)** it's shorter both in the definition and the implementation, and most importantly **3)** it preserves type safety.

Comment: I do understand the advantages of lambdas, and I sense that i have not clearly described my aim. I have one extension method on DataSet and want to be able to transfer the data of any object of any type(!) to DataTable instances. How do i write lambdas for properties i do not know at design time? Thats where the reflection comes in. :-)

Comment: @Udontknow, Your question already used a generic version of `CreateGetPropertyFunc<T>`, I only extended it. If you need to get property getters of unknown types, please change your question to reflect that (so we'll see what your current approach is).

Comment: I do not understand why the use of a generic type argument would imply knowing about existing properties? I thought i wrote it clearly with "i dont want to write special code for each type defining which properties need to be written down"... Anyway, i´ll try to clarify it.